# My app doesn't recognize data from model file

Tags: flutter, api, rest, httprequest, httpresponse

Hello this is my model file;

```js
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final hisselist = hisselistFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Hisselist hisselistFromJson(String str) => Hisselist.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String hisselistToJson(Hisselist data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Hisselist {
  Hisselist({
    required this.success,
    required this.result,
  });

  bool success;
  List<dynamic> result;

  factory Hisselist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Hisselist(
    success: json["success"],
    result: List<dynamic>.from(json["result"].map((x) => x)),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "success": success,
    "result": List<dynamic>.from(result.map((x) => x)),
  };
}

class ResultClass {
  ResultClass({
    required this.rate,
    required this.lastprice,
    required this.lastpricestr,
    required this.hacim,
    required this.hacimstr,
    required this.text,
    required this.code,
  });

  double rate;
  double lastprice;
  String lastpricestr;
  double hacim;
  String hacimstr;
  String text;
  String code;

  factory ResultClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResultClass(
    rate: json["rate"].toDouble(),
    lastprice: json["lastprice"].toDouble(),
    lastpricestr: json["lastpricestr"],
    hacim: json["hacim"].toDouble(),
    hacimstr: json["hacimstr"],
    text: json["text"],
    code: json["code"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "rate": rate,
    "lastprice": lastprice,
    "lastpricestr": lastpricestr,
    "hacim": hacim,
    "hacimstr": hacimstr,
    "text": text,
    "code": code,
  };
}
```

And this is my file where i call API

```js
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';

import '../models/apis/hisselist.dart';

class Stocks extends StatefulWidget {
  Stocks({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StocksState createState() => _StocksState();
}

class _StocksState extends State<Stocks> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {



  ScrollController? controller;
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final url = Uri.parse('https://api.collectapi.com/economy/hisseSenedi');
  var counter;
  var hisseResult;
  Future callHisse() async {
    try{
      Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'apikey xxx'
      };
      final response = await http.get(url,headers:requestHeaders);

      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        var result = hisselistFromJson(response.body);
        if(mounted);
        setState(() {
          counter = 200;
          hisseResult = result;
        });
        return result;
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    callHisse();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
            'Hisseler'
        ).tr(),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: counter != null ?

          ListView.builder(
              itemCount: counter,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(hisseResult.data[index].code),
                    subtitle: Text(hisseResult.data[index].text),
                  ),
                );
          }) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(

          )),
        ),
      ),

    );


  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

And I'm getting this error?
[image]

What's wrong with it?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hisselist class has only two properties, *success* and *result*.

This line of code returns result that is Hisselist type:

```
var result = hisselistFromJson(response.body);
```

You should avoid using *var* type here and set Hisselist instead:

```
Hisselist? result = hisselistFromJson(response.body);
```

hisseResult variable is also Hisselist type so you can only use *success* and *result* properties, there is no *data* property defined in Hisselist class.

**Hisselist? hisseResult** instead od var type.

```
  title: Text(hisseResult?.result[index].code ?? ""),
  subtitle: Text(hisseResult?.result[index].text ?? ""),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/15728644/miktad,  List<dynamic> result ->

Change dynamic to ResultClass, also in fromJson and toJson

Comment: Can you explain better please? Shall i change all dynamic to ResultClass? There are 6 dynamic in the code

Comment: List<dynamic> result;  AND 

 result: List<dynamic>.from(json["result"].map((x) => x)) in fromJson and toJson

Comment: It should be like this? 
  bool success;
  List<ResultClass> result;

  factory Hisselist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Hisselist(
    success: json["success"],
    result: List<ResultClass>.from(json["result"].map((x) => x)),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "success": success,
    "result": List<ResultClass>.from(result.map((x) => x)),
  };

Comment: yes yes, that should be ok

Comment: I'm starting to run the app now, hope it works, thank you for your helping. I'll let you know if it works and mark your answer aş the correct answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247241/discussion-between-miktad-and-starscream).

Answer (score 1):

There is no field as it described on your model class
I think you want result.

Try `var hisseResult;` to `Hisselist? hisseResult;`

```dart
title: Text(hisseResult?.result[index].code??""),
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now:
NoSuchMethodError : Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String,dynamic>' has no instance getter 'code'.   Receiver: _LinkedHashmap len:12 Tried calling: code

Answer (score 0):

hisseResult.result[index]  replace for hisseResult.data[index]
itemCount: hisseResult.result.length replace for itemCount: counter,